# AngularJs: How to Assign a value to ng-model based on user-based DropDown Selection

Tags: angularjs

I was trying to use a drop-down Selection and use the "Selected" value to assign the model of the Search Box to one of the following values:

```
ng-model=searchText.$  (For search across Any of the 3 fields)
ng-model=searchText.name (For search only on name field) 
ng-model=searchText.age (For search only on age field)
ng-model=searchText.gender (For search only on gender field)
```

The above ng-model of the Search Box - would subsequently be used to filter a JavaScript Array of Objects.

Despite Googling for more than 3 days, and trying various "tricks" such as using

```
"ng-model=searchText.{{filterTypeSelectModel}}"
```

I have been unable to set the ng-model value based on user-based DropDown Filter Selection.

Right now, the Filter works only if I hardcode the value of ng-model at the time of writing the code. I have been unable to assign ng-model at Run-Time or based on user's selection of the drop-down Filter.

My Failed attempt would help further explain what I am trying to achieve:

- https://jsfiddle.net/pmkumaar/d50c7tmr/

Any Assistance to "dynamically" assign and link the Drop-down Selection to the ng-model value of the Search Box  would be most appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try 
`<input ng-model="searchText[filterTypeSelectModel]">`
here is updated fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/d50c7tmr/9/

Comment: Nice answer!  That looks like just what the OP was looking for!

Comment: Appreciate it! Solves the problem. I however, need to tidy up my code as subsequent filtering remembers the previous filtered list and therefore uses that subset as the  "source" list.